# After updating Jenkins, configure pages were visually broken

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I updated Jenkins from version 2.252 to 2.313. But then when I went to a job's configure page, the page was visually broken. The Jenkins logo and header appeared twice on the page, and some parts were repeated.

Comment: Did you read the [Changelog](https://www.jenkins.io/changelog-stable/#v2.277.1) and [upgrade guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide//) ([2.263.x](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.263/)) before proceeding?

Comment: I don't see any mention of this issue there. See my Answer below.

Comment: So long ago, wrong release notes: [see 2.277.x](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.277/), [incompatible plugins](https://issues.jenkins.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa?selectPageId=20741), [JENKINS-65263](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-65263). Read LTS changelog, upgrade notes, update plugins, go to next LTS, update plugins, repeat until current.

Answer (score 2):

After updating to the latest version of the Jenkins plugin "Publish Over SSH" (I updated from 1.20.1 to 1.22), the configure page looked normal again.